# Thread safe copying of a deque without blocking append

Tags: python, multithreading, deque

I'm trying to create a circular buffer in python.
My best implementation is by using `deque` with fixed length.
(basic implementation)

```
class RingBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.mutex = Lock()
        self.deque = collections.deque(maxlen=size)

    def push_elem(self, element):
        copy.deepcopy(element)
        with self.mutex:
            self.deque.append(element)

    def get_data(self, event, callback=None):
        with self.mutex:
            return copy.deepcopy(list(self.deque))


    def get_elem(self):
        if self.deque:
            with self.mutex:
                return cp.deepcopy(self.deque[-1])
        return None
```

I know that that appending and deleting elements from both sides is thread safe but I also need to be able to copy N-number of elements. This is why I'm using this mutex.
The problem is that I don't want to block the insertion of new elements while some other thread is copying the data in the buffer.
**Is there a way to achieve this behavior without the mutex?**

Comment: Are you asking about lock-free programing? That's very complicated and pointless in Python anyway (at least one mutex in Python is unavoidable: GIL). Or do you want reader and inserter to be able to run concurrently (in other words you want short-lived mutex)?

Comment: @freakish I want to not block the append operation while copying the buffer data. For example : the deque contains 30 elements(ints from 0 to 29) I want to copy 20 from right (9 to 29). While this is happening I want to still be able to push new elements to the buffer from different thread without waiting on mutex

Comment: Right, so operations you've got here are CRUD (Create Read Update Delete), possibly only CRD. So the "lock everything" strategy you have now is a pessimistic [concurrency control method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Concurrency_control_mechanisms). There are others, e.g. [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) implemented in PostgreSQL. Anyway this is a huge topic and these algorithms are not easy. Don't expect it to implement this via some magic trick. Most likely you need to change your data structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, this copy is atomic (once it starts to run):

```
s = list(islice(some_deque, 20))
```

The list building, slicing with itertools, and deque iteration are all implemented in C with no pure python callbacks.  Also, the copy operation doesn't cause any DECREFs to fall to zero, thus eliminating another source of non-atomic behavior.